# Get most recent date when a value changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table of client account balance, the first one had the clients with debit account, the second had the details of account balance.
Data will be like this:

TABLE A

```
 id_account |  balance
 -----------|---------
    1       |  -50
```

TABLE B

```
id_account  |  data   | date
------------|---------|-----------
   1        |   -50   | 20/10/2018
   1        |   -30   | 09/10/2018
   1        |    30   | 01/10/2018
   1        |    20   | 25/09/2018
   1        |  -100   | 01/08/2018
```

i want to get the last date when he become debtor.

```
 id account |  balance | debit date
------------|----------|-----------
    1       |    -50   | 09/10/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can do this with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*, debit_date
FROM @tablea AS a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(date) AS debit_date
    FROM @tableb AS b
    WHERE b.id_account = a.id_account
    AND   b.data < 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @tableb AS x
        WHERE x.id_account = b.id_account
        AND   x.date > b.date
        AND   x.data >= 0
    )
) AS OA
```

The `OUTER APPLY` part selects all rows where balance is negative (-50, -30, -100) then removes those for which a newer row exists with positive balance (for -100 the newer rows with positive balance are 20 and 30). After filtering you just need the minimum date.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7806d9e9d8698e6d317f95899664640c)

Comment: your solution works also but it takes a lot of time given the large amount of data (over than 20 millions records in table B) thank you

Comment: @ramy I focused on getting the correct answer. For performance, it might be possible to write the above logic in different ways e.g. change outer apply to a group by query and join with table-a.

Comment: @Ramy 20 millions is always going to be slow. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=34db5a7b1eb3d982ed235b70ef0a609f for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Following Salman's comment and using the link to DBFiddle he published in his answer, I came up with a better solution:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT account, Data, Date, 
           ISNULL(LAG(Data) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY Date), 1) As PrevData
    FROM TableB
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT account, Data, Date, PrevData,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY Date DESC) As rn
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE Data < 0 AND PrevData > 0
)

SELECT a.account, balance, b.Date
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN CTE2 b 
    ON a.account = b.account
    AND rn = 1
```

Note really simpler than Salman's answer, just another option that should give correct results. Note that if the account never had a negative sum in tableB, no date will be returned.

[DB Fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d134eff28cfc3c3387707c722d6b5ec3)

### First version

The simplest solution I found was selecting from TableA and joining a derived table based on TableB:

```
SELECT a.account, balance, b.Date
FROM TableA a
JOIN (
    SELECT account, Data, Date, 
           LAG(Data) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY Date) As PrevData
    FROM TableB
) b ON a.account = b.account
WHERE b.Data < 0 AND b.PrevData > 0
```

Comment: Will fail if you insert a negative value between 20 and 30.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks for the catch (and the DBFiddle you posted). That allowed me to fix my answer.

Comment: the solution of salmon works perfectly but he take a long of time, your's is faster but on the other hand, it does not respond to the need, for example if I add the record ('1', '60', '01/07/2018') it will brings 01/08/2018, however Salmon solution will bring 09/10/2018 thank you in advance

Comment: Row_number should be ordered by date desc. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)))

Answer (score 0):

This not exactly that you want, but as per sample data you can do :

```
select a.*, b.date as bebit_date
from tablea a outer apply
     ( select top (1) b.*
       from tableb b
       where b.id = a.id and b.data < a.balance
       order by b.date desc
     ) b;
```

If i go with your description them i would use `row_number()` :

```
select t.id, t.balance, t.date as debit_date
from (select a.*, b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.id order by b.date desc) as seq
      from tablea a inner join
           tableb b
           on b.id = a.id
     ) t
where seq = 2;
```

Comment: What if you add `('1', '-60', '21/10/2018')` that will not bring `09/10/2018`

Comment: if you add ('1', '-60', '21/10/2018') then the result must be the same, i try to get the first time when the account becomes debtor after having credit balance for last time. Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this query

```
 Select 
    Id,
    balance,
    x.Date As debitDate
From TableA
Cross Apply
(
   Select top 1
         [Date]
   From TableB
   Where TableA.Id = TableB.Id
   Order by [Date] desc
) As x
```

Comment: Is there a new clause `Ordery`? Is there a column `x`? and that is not what OP want.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data for the dates he was a debtor and use Row_number() to list them in a descending order. Then joining the output with the other two tables and taking the 2 top will give the last date when he was a debtor.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_account, a.balance, c.date FROM  #tablea a join #tableb b
ON a.id_account=b.id_account 
JOIN (SELECT b.id_account, max(b.date) date, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_account ORDER BY b.date DESC) rn FROM #tableb b GROUP BY b.id_account, b.data, b.date HAVING b.data <0) c 
ON c.id_account = a.id_account 
WHERE c.rn = 2
```